# How to change the Keyboard input on MAC via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Currently trying to update the keyboard input for a mac using a terminal script.

Can anyone suggest a line of code to change it to the US format?

Reason being that it needs to be through terminal is that the mac is controlled through Jamf so looking to deploy a script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change OSX keyboard layout("input source") programmatically via terminal or AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729704/change-osx-keyboard-layoutinput-source-programmatically-via-terminal-or-appl)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this article it is a bit old but that is essentialy what we do too. We have a installer pkg with the plists wich define the keyboard layout wich we got from factory machines.

```
Library > Preferences:
.GlobalPreferences.plist
com.apple.HIToolbox.plist

Users > admin > Library > Preferences:
.GlobalPreferences.plist

Users > admin > Library > Preferences > ByHost:
com.apple.HIToolbox.<UID>.plist
```

Make sure you deploy it with FUT and FEU in a dmg when you want now users to have the keyboard layout. We have a PKG because we have it in our selfservice for people to chose.
https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/10976/help-to-setup-os-user-keyboard-language-during-imaging

Jhon

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

This answer for determining the Keyboard input sources should help you to change the format to US: [Determine OS X keyboard layout ("input source") in the terminal/a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597804/determine-os-x-keyboard-layout-input-source-in-the-terminal-a-script)

Use a shell script (or any other comfortable scripting language to update the property plist)